# Generating virtual methods in template base class for optional override in inheriting class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

What I want is a template class that, given tuple, and used as a base class, provides method with default behavior for each type of element in tuple. These methods should be virtual, so that they could be overridden in inheriting class.

Code below does exactly that:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

template <typename Class, uint16_t tag>
struct def {
        using message_type = Class;
        static constexpr uint16_t class_tag = tag;
};

// (3) adding "constexpr" or "const" causes compilation failure
auto t = std::make_tuple(def<A, 0>(), def<B, 1>(), def<C, 2>());

template <typename T> // (1)
struct base_handler_t {
        virtual void h(T const& t) { std::cout << "base_handler_t\n"; }
};

template <typename ...Ts> // (2) - adding "const" to "std::tuple<Ts...>" in line below makes code work again if "t" is constant
struct base_handler_t<std::tuple<Ts...>> : public base_handler_t<typename Ts::message_type>...{
        using base_handler_t<typename Ts::message_type>::h...;
};

struct service_t : public base_handler_t<decltype(t)> {
        using base_handler_t<decltype(t)>::h;
        void h(B const & b) {
                std::cout << "service_t\n";
        }
};

int main() {
        service_t n;
        n.h(A());
        n.h(B());
}
```

EDIT AFTER FINDING EXACT AND MINIMAL EXAMPLE THAT BREAKS CODE:

Code above works fine when entered as-is, but if line below comment `(3)` (about adding `constexpr` to definition of `t`) is changed to either:

```cpp
const auto t = std::make_tuple(def<A, 0>(), def<B, 1>(), def<C, 2>());
```

or

```cpp
constexpr auto t = std::make_tuple(def<A, 0>(), def<B, 1>(), def<C, 2>());
```

code fails to compile. Compiler claims that:

```cpp
x.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
x.cc:35:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘service_t::h(A)’
   35 |         n.h(A());
      |                ^
x.cc:28:14: note: candidate: ‘void service_t::h(const B&)’
   28 |         void h(B const & b) {
      |              ^
x.cc:28:26: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A’ to ‘const B&’
   28 |         void h(B const & b) {
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~^
x.cc:18:22: note: candidate: ‘void base_handler_t<T>::h(const T&) [with T = const std::tuple<def<A, 0>, def<B, 1>, def<C, 2> >]’
   18 |         virtual void h(T const& t) { std::cout << "base_handler_t\n"; }
      |                      ^
x.cc:18:33: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A’ to ‘const std::tuple<def<A, 0>, def<B, 1>, def<C, 2> >&’
   18 |         virtual void h(T const& t) { std::cout << "base_handler_t\n"; }
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~^
```

I assumed that when it comes to templates, there is no real difference if type is extracted from constant or variable.

Code starts to work after changing in line below (2):

```cpp
struct base_handler_t<std::tuple<Ts...>> : ...
```

to

```cpp
struct base_handler_t<const std::tuple<Ts...>> : ...
```

Why is it so? Is it because `std::tuple<Ts...>` does not match `const std::tuple<Ts...>` exactly? What are exact rules that govern this case?

Thanks in advance.

ORIGINAL PLEAD FOR HELP:

In original code base methods for each type (A, B and C in example above) are defined in "service_t" class by hand. I attempted to solve this problem exactly as in example above. As long as all methods were present, code still worked fine. As soon as I commented out single method I received error that there is no matching method to call, followed by list of possible matches. There was match for method with argument `std::tuple<def<....` and so on - it seems that while in my snippet above everything works fine (so one method is generated for each tuple element type), there's *something* preventing larger code base from matching template (2) and instead it uses template (1).

I'd like to hear *any* idea why this would fail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your code which fails?

Comment: In particular, illustrate somehow what you mean by "*As soon as I commented out single method*."

Comment: It is hard to find a bug in code we cannot see.

Comment: Yeah, i know that it is hard to f8nd bug in bug code that you cannot see,, taht is why i asked for suggestions. Original code is much, much larger and proprietary, this is why i tried to provide a snippet, which, to my dismay, works. I will try to replicate my code so that is resembles original as much as possible.

Comment: You've been active on this site for five years. Has no one told you about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I found exact failure's reason. Error can be reproduced after following comments in added part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

`auto t = std::make_tuple(def<A, 0>(), def<B, 1>(), def<C, 2>());`

`decltype(t)` is `std::tuple<def<A, 0>, def<B, 1>, def<C, 2>>`

If `t` is `const` qualified: `const auto t = /*..*/`, then, `decltype(t)` is `const std::tuple<def<A, 0>, def<B, 1>, def<C, 2>>`.

So for `base_handler_t<decltype(t)>`, `base_handler_t<const std::tuple<def<A, 0>, def<B, 1>, def<C, 2>>>` match only primary template definition, not your specialization.

You might use instead `base_handler_t<std::remove_const_t<decltype(t)>>` or `base_handler_t<std::decay_t<decltype(t)>>` (remove reference and then cv qualifiers)

Comment: Ok, I understand. I simply thought that templates do not look at CV-qualification (or whatever you call it) of passed type , because e.g. you can't declare template with integral, non-const type. This answers my question completely, thank you.

Comment: @JędrzejDudkiewicz: How do you implement/use traits like `std::is_const`, `std::remove_const` else ...

Comment: This would still works in this imaginary world of mine, because even though type is CV-qualified (and can be pointer, reference etc.), it would match type without these if it were better match than catch-all, and when passed as simple template <typename T> it would retain these properties so that it could be used later - but yeah, I guess that wasn't very thought out. Never the less thanks for explanation and quick lesson :)